# Excel VBA Autofill Destination

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

Need some help with this line of code:

```
.Range("A1:G1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:U1")
```

I'm trying to automate making a calendar. The code won't compile if I change the range to any value except `A1:U1`. I would like to extend the range to `A1:AE1`

Any reason why it's stuck and not compiling there?

Thanks!

```
Sub CreateCalendar()
Dim lMonth As Long
Dim strMonth As String
Dim rStart As Range
Dim strAddress As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lDays As Long
Dim dDate As Date
    'Add new sheet and format


    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
        With Cells
            .ColumnWidth = 6#
            .Font.Size = 8
        End With
    'Create the Month headings
    For lMonth = 1 To 12
            Select Case lMonth
                    Case 1
                        strMonth = "January"
                        Set rStart = Range("A1")
                    Case 2
                        strMonth = "February"
                        Set rStart = Range("A3")
                    Case 3
                        strMonth = "March"
                        Set rStart = Range("A5")
                    Case 4
                        strMonth = "April"
                        Set rStart = Range("A7")
                    Case 5
                        strMonth = "May"
                        Set rStart = Range("A9")
                    Case 6
                        strMonth = "June"
                        Set rStart = Range("A11")
                    Case 7
                        strMonth = "July"
                        Set rStart = Range("A13")
                    Case 8
                        strMonth = "August"
                        Set rStart = Range("A15")
                    Case 9
                        strMonth = "September"
                        Set rStart = Range("A17")
                    Case 10
                        strMonth = "October"
                        Set rStart = Range("A19")
                    Case 11
                        strMonth = "November"
                        Set rStart = Range("A21")
                    Case 12
                        strMonth = "December"
                        Set rStart = Range("A23")
            End Select
            'Merge, AutoFill and align months
            With rStart
                .Value = strMonth
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                .Font.Bold = True
                    With .Range("A1:G1")
                        .Merge
                        .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
                    End With
                **.Range("A1:G1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:U1")**
            End With
    Next lMonth
     'Pass ranges for months
     For lMonth = 1 To 12
        strAddress = Choose(lMonth, "A2:AE2", "A4:AE4", "A6:AE6", _
                            "A8:AE8", "A10:AE10", "A12:AE12", _
                            "A14:AE14", "A16:AE16", "A18:AE18", _
                            "A20:AE20", "A22:AE22", "A24:AE24")
        lDays = 0
        Range(strAddress).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
        'Add dates to month range and format
        For Each rCell In Range(strAddress)
            lDays = lDays + 1
            dDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), lMonth, lDays)
                If Month(dDate) = lMonth Then ' It's a valid date
                    With rCell
                        .Value = dDate
                        .NumberFormat = "ddd dd"
                    End With
                End If
        Next rCell
    Next lMonth
    'add con formatting
     With Range("A1:AE28")
           .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=TODAY()"
           .FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
           .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the actual error message that you get?

Comment: The reason it wont work is because AE doesnt fit in the merged cell range when you try and auto fill, it will work if you choose AB or AI .. AE is column 31, you have merged 7 cells, 31 doesnt divide by 7 (At least not into whole numbers) .. Pick a cell which is divisible by 7 and you are good to go

Comment: I'm still getting the 1004 error. I might not explain clearly, I want between 28-31 columns merged (max), to be sort of a separator between the dates.

Comment: @Collin : Take a look at my answer. Do you want to merge only until the last date of the month? Or to have a rectangular array?

Comment: The actual question that you're asking is almost completely unrelated to your original post. The reason for the error message has been explained. What you actually want help with has only been partly explained within a comment in response to one of the answers. Please overhaul to question to ask exactly what you're trying to achieve. Autofill will have no part in the additional separation fields to be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explain many times, the issue is that `A:G` is 7 columns,
so you'll have to use `AutoFill` on a range that has a number of columns that is a multiple of 7!

Optimized code for Working solution on `A:AE` :

```
Sub CreateCalendar()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim lMonth As Long
Dim DateMidMonth As Date
Dim LastDayOfMonth As Integer
Dim strMonth As String
Dim rStart As Range
Dim Row1 As Integer
Dim rCell As Range

ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True

    'Add new sheet and format
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    With wS
        With .Cells
            .ColumnWidth = 6#
            .Font.Size = 8
        End With '.Cells

        For lMonth = 1 To 12
            DateMidMonth = CDate(lMonth & "/15/2017")
            LastDayOfMonth = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateMidMonth, 0))
            strMonth = Format(DateMidMonth, "MMMM")
            Row1 = 1 + (lMonth - 1) * 2

            '''Create the Month headings
            Set rStart = .Range("A" & Row1)
            Set rStart = .Range(rStart, rStart.Offset(0, LastDayOfMonth - 1))
            '''Merge, AutoFill and align months
            With rStart
                .Merge
                .Value = strMonth
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                .Font.Bold = True
                .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous

                '''Create days
                With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, .Columns.Count)
                    .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
                    .NumberFormat = "ddd dd"
                    'Add dates to month range
                    For Each rCell In .Cells
                        rCell.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), lMonth, rCell.Column)
                    Next rCell
                End With '.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, .Columns.Count)
            End With 'rStart
        Next lMonth

        '''add conditional formatting
         With .Range("A1:AE28")
               .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=TODAY()"
               .FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
               .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        End With '.Range("A1:AE28")
    End With 'wS
End Sub
```

Output (in French) :

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I know it will compile however I want the months to be just once. 28-31 columns to be merged. sorry if I didn't explain clearly. Is there any workaround to this instead of having it divided by 7?

Comment: @Collin : Sure, it's just that everyone thought that it was vooluntary to have 7 columns like 7 days in a week! Give me a minute to edit! ;)

Comment: @Collin : Give it a try! ;)

Comment: One small request, how do I add several blank rows (4) after the Days row? which line should I add to do the modification?

Comment: @Collin : Change `Row1 = 1 + (lMonth - 1) * 2` to `Row1 = 1 + (lMonth - 1) * 6`

Comment: Thanks that's simple. One last one, I'm trying to start the output from row 2 column B. I've managed to get to row 2 but Tried changing .Range("B"), Tried adding offset but I end up with all the Date 1 to be at the end of the month instead. Where do I went wrong? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Collin : Change `Set rStart = .Range("A" & Row1)` to `Set rStart = .Range("B" & Row1)` and don't forget to adjust the part for conditional formatting! ;)

Comment: I did change .Range ("B") that but all the months starts from 2nd instead. and I actually remove the conditional Formatting part. Any ideas why? Oh and month February has Date 01 at the end of the month.

Comment: @Collin : I don't see how it could be possible to have that issue if you ONLY change `Row1 = ...` to `Row1 = 2 + (lMonth - 1) * 6` and `Set rStart = .Range("A" & Row1)` to `Set rStart = .Range("B" & Row1)`... You probably have something else different than the code in my answer, take a closer look

Answer (score 3):

Tried running your code with AE1, got this error:

[image]

This is actually a run-time error, not a compile error. (A compile error won't even let you enter the routine, possibly due to an undeclared variable or invalid syntax)

When filling across with merged cells, you need to a fill an even multiple of the number of merged cells. With A1:G1 merged, you need to merge to either AB or AI to be an even multiple of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `Type` to your `Autofill`?

Such as:

```
Type:=xlFillDefault 

.Range("A1:G1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:U1"),Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: This won't be useful, as this is the default property which is used implicitly and more importantly because it is working with merged cells, so it is suppose to be a multiple of the length of those cells